# Cron job for php script that requires VERY long execution time

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script run as a cron job that executes a set of simple tasks that loops for each user in the database and takes about 30 mins to complete.  This process starts over every hour and needs to be as fast and efficient as possible. The problem Im having, is like with any server script, execution time varies and I need to figure out the best cron time settings.

If I run cron every minute, I need to stop the last loop of the script 20 seconds before the end of the minute to make sure that the current loop finishes in time. Over the course of the hour this adds up to a lot of wasted time.

Im wondering if its a bad idea to simple remove the php execution time limit and run the script once an hour and let it run to completion.... is this a bad idea?

Comment: Is your cron job calling a website running PHP or using PHP from the command line?

I don't fully understand the second paragraph -- why do you stop the processing and restarting every minute?

Comment: I think you may get some more productive answers here if you explain what the job needs to do. There may be a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: If calling a long running cron job using wget, consider setting number of tries to 1 using -t 1 so it only is called once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you'd like the work done ASAP, don't use cron.  Cron is good for things that need to happen at specific times.  It's often abused to simulate a background process that would ideally process work as soon as work appears.  You should probably write a daemon that runs continuously.  (Note: you could also look at a message/work-queue type system, there are nice libraries out there to do this too)

You can write a daemon from scratch using the [pcntl functions](https://www.php.net/pcntl) (since you don't care about multiple worker processes, it's [super-easy](http://blog.icerock.com.ar/2010/10/daemon-in-4-lines-of-code/) to get a process running in the background.), or cheat and just make a script that runs forever and run it via [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), or leverage some solid library code like PEAR's [System:Daemon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon) or [nanoserv](http://nanoserv.si.kz/)

Once the daemonization stuff is taken care of, all you really care about is having a loop that runs forever.  You'll want to take care that your script doesn't leak memory, or consume too many resources.

Generally, you can do something like:

```
<?PHP
// some setup code 
while(true){
    $todo = figureOutIfIHaveWorkToDo();
    foreach($todo as $something){
        //do stuff with $something
        //remember to clean up resources so you don't leak memory!
        usleep(/*some integer*/);
    }
    usleep(/* some other integer */); 
}
```

And it'll work pretty well.

Comment: what if the php.ini file has max_execution_time = 30 ?, the script gonna terminated after 30 second.

Comment: @KiranManiya - Nope!  You would think so, but php-cli ignores the value.  Write a trivial test script and see for yourself.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of setting the `max_execution_time` you could also use [set_time_limit()](http://us.php.net/set_time_limit) to reset the counter on every loop. This will ensure your script is never running out of time unless there is something serious hanging within the current loop (and taking longer than the max_execution_time).

Basically this should make your script run as long as it needs while giving it a 30 seconds timeout between two `set_time_limit()` calls.

Comment: This is a good advice. I am not sure why you don't have enough votes.

Comment: this trick is pure magic! I never thought it would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the time limit to 0 and letting it do its thing is fairly typical of PHP based cronjobs (in my experience), but this is also the point when you should ask yourself a few important questions, such as "Should I rewrite this job in a compiled language?" and "Am I using all of my tools (database, etc) to their maximum efficiency?"

That said, maybe better than completely removing the time limit would be to set it to the upper limit you actually want.  If that means 48 minutes, then `set_time_limit(48 * 60);`

Answer (score 1):

I really think you shouldn't set the time out to 0, that is just looking for trouble. At most, set it to 59*60 seconds, but setting it to 0 might cause security problems, if a script hangs, it will hang almost forever until the server host stops the execution. It is considered bad practice to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the php command-line interface for similar long running tasks in the past. You probably do not want to remove the execution time limit for any request.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a great idea if there's little chance that it will take more than an hour.  Note, however, that the wrong bug can be a really good way of making it take longer than expected..

To avoid all sorts of nasty problems, you should have a guard file with the process ID of the script.  On startup, you should check to make sure the file doesn't exist, or if it does that the process ID in the file doesn't exist (through a kill( pid, 0 ) call).  If these conditions are met, create a new file with the script's PID and delete the file when you're done.

This is the same trick that many daemons use to ensure it isn't already running.  If the daemon was killed suddenly, the file will still exist but the PID of the process therein is unlikely to be running.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your script does, it can lead to problems if you remove the time limit. If per example, you are polling an external server that is unresponsive while the job is running, and that your cron takes 2 hours instead of 30 minutes to complete, you may get a stack of PHP processes being fired up even if the previous ones haven't completed yet. This can cause system instability and crashes.

You probably have two options:

- Make sure that no other instance of your script is running beforehand, otherwise exit() on start.
- Consider changing your cronjob into a daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to run hourly like clockwork?

If not split the job (you mentioned it was more than one simple task) do each task every hour?

Or split it per user, do A-M on hour, then N-Z the next?