# PHP Cron job execution time limits fail

Tags: php, curl, cron, timeout

I've got a CronJob scheduled to run every 7 minutes. The script runs a loop over a number of users and sends email via SMTP or does some API calls via curl.

Thus, most of the execution time is apparently spent outside the realm tracked by `max_execution_time` on Linux. So, because I was experiencing hangs in my script that were always fixed by restarting it (I'm also looking for the cause of the hangs, but wasn't successful so far).

Because with set_time_limit set to 6 minutes, the script still ran 30 minutes sometimes, I now check `microtime(true)` after each round in the loop and break out of it, if it has been running more than 6 minutes.

Still, the script sometimes runs 37 minutes (even though I can see that emails, which map to one round in a loop, still go off).

The only trick I have left is [`pcntl_fork`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493676/detecting-a-timeout-for-a-block-of-code-in-php/7493838#7493838). I am reluctant to employ it because of platform dependence, and because I figured using a loop and `microtime(true)` should track time spent outside the process too and I'd like to understand why this isn't the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going outside PHP to get the time, this is simple, works and doesn't require me to learn to deal with pcntl functions.

```
$time_comp = microtime(true); // save start time
function check_time_against_mysql($dbh,$time_comp) // run this function
{                                                  // to see how much time passed
    $time = $dbh->prepare("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - :created AS time_in_seconds");
    $time->bindValue(":created",$time_comp);
    $time->execute() or die("fail time");
    $time_passed = $time->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return floatval($time_passed['time_in_seconds']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `max_execution_time` is used for limiting script execution time. However this does not affect system calls. See the [manpage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

You can also use [`set_time_limit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to properly set the maximum amount of time a script can run. This only changes the time_limit for the script in scope. Have you tried this as well?

You can find another question that has been asked may help slightly at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082745/cron-job-for-php-script-that-requires-very-long-execution-time).

Comment: Thanks, I know system calls aren't tracked on Linux and I use `set_time_limit` too, I tried to convey these facts in my question. Thanks for the link to the other question, maybe I should look at using a proper daemon, but that still would leave me without a working tool to catch buggy long-running routines.